# Return id where one of two fields matches a value, but only the field other than that vaue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a messages table that has both a `to_id` and a `from_id` for a given message.

I'd like to pass a user_id to this query and have it return a non-duplicate list of id's, representing any users that has a message to/from the supplied user_id.

What I have right now is (using 12 as the target user_id) :

```
SELECT from_id, to_id

FROM messages

WHERE 
from_id = 12 
OR 
to_id = 12
```

This does return all records where that user_id exists, but I'm not sure how to have it only return non-duplicates, and ONLY one field which would be the user_id that is not 12.

In short, it would return the id's of any users that user 12 has an existing message record with.

I hope I have explained this well enough, I have to believe it's relatively simple that I have not learned yet.

EDIT :

I should have specified that while my current SQL has two fields, I want only one field to be returned --- contact_id. And there should be no duplicates.

contact_id is not a field in the messages table, but that is the field name I'd like the query to return, regardless of whether it is returning the from_id or to_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`union`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
select
 from_id as contact_id
from messages
where to_id = 12
union
select
 to_id
from messages
where from_id = 12
```

Also, from [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) (emphasis mine):

> The default behavior for UNION is that **duplicate rows are removed** from the result.

Alternatively, you could use [`if()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) (or [`case`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)):

```
select distinct
 if(from_id = 12, to_id, from_id) as contact_id
from messages
where from_id = 12
or to_id = 12
```

Comment: This query seems to always returning the from_id, and in some cases that is 12. I'd like it to only return one field named contact_id.

Comment: Do you actually have any data which satisfies the criteria of the second query, i.e.: `where from_id = 12`?

Comment: yes, but I see the issue in that some messages were sent from the same id. So I need to handle that.

Comment: Then explicitly filter where `to_id != from_id`

Comment: I'm going to restrict messages to the same user_id, so that won't matter. But will add that to the query just in case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution avoiding a union statement.

```
SELECT distinct (case when to_id = 12 then from_id else to_id end) as contact_id

FROM messages

WHERE 
   from_id = 12 
OR 
    to_id = 12
```

Comment: ok, this returns records, but there are duplicates. Plus ideally it would return a query with just one field - like contact_id. I'll add that to my question, I don't think I was clear in that I wanted one field back.

Comment: I don't get duplicates when I use the distinct keyword.

Comment: yes, I apologize, I didn't realize that there was a record where the to_id and from_id matched, which allowed that to happen I believe.

Comment: actually, this is not working, because there is no contact_id field in that table. But that is the name of the field I wanted it to return. For example if from_id was 111, then contact_id should have the value of to_id. And visa versa.

Comment: Thanks for that update, I was not aware you could do a case like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to UNION two queries.